# Action during Cypress multiple click

Tags: cypress

Is it possible to make some verification on several elements after click() with option `{multiple:true}`?

I have to check text after each click on several buttons with the same selector.
What I want to do:

```js
cy.get(".copy-button").click({multiple: true}).then(() => {
    cy.get(".tooltip-name").should('contain', 'Copied successfully!')
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do with `each()`, something like:

```js
cy.get('.copy-button').each(($ele) => {
  cy.wrap($ele).click()
  cy.get('.tooltip-name')
    .should('be.visible')
    .and('contain', 'Copied successfully!')
})
```